# Can someone combine this HTML with CSS and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to combine HTML, CSS and JavaScript into one file. I feel like I am probably missing a simple HTML element. However, I'm not exactly sure if `script` would work as there is quite a lot of Javascript code and `script` seems more like an element for quick javascript code insertion into an HTML file.

HTML:

```
<div class="clock-container">
  <div class="clock-col">
    <p class="clock-hours clock-timer">
    </p>
    <p class="clock-label">
      Hours
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="clock-col">
    <p class="clock-minutes clock-timer">
    </p>
    <p class="clock-label">
      Minutes
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="clock-col">
    <p class="clock-seconds clock-timer">
    </p>
    <p class="clock-label">
      Seconds
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.clock {
  &-day {
    &:before {
      content: var(--timer-day);
    }
  }
  &-hours {
    &:before {
      content: var(--timer-hours);
    }
  }
  &-minutes {
    &:before {
      content: var(--timer-minutes);
    }
  }
  &-seconds {
    &:before {
      content: var(--timer-seconds);
    }
  }
}

body {
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, #1870ed 0, #f18f88 100%);
  font-family: 'Montserrat', 'sans-serif';
  min-height: 100vh; 
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.clock {
  &-container {
    margin-top: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    background-color: #080808;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 60px 20px;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px rgba(255,255,255,.15), 0 15px 90px 30px rgba(0,0,0,.25);
    display: flex;
  }
  &-col {
    text-align: center;
    margin-right: 40px;
    margin-left: 40px;
    min-width: 90px;
    position: relative;
    &:not(:last-child):before,
    &:not(:last-child):after{
      content: "";
      background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.3);
      height: 5px;
      width: 5px;
      border-radius: 50%;
      display: block;
      position: absolute;
      right: -42px;
    }
    &:not(:last-child):before {
      top: 35%;
    }
    &:not(:last-child):after {
      top: 50%;
    }
  }
  &-timer {
    &:before {
      color: #fff;
      font-size: 4.2rem;
      text-transform: uppercase;
    }
  }
  &-label {
    color: rgba(255,255,255,.35);
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: .7rem;
    margin-top: 10px;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 825px) {
  .clock-container {
  flex-direction: column;
    padding-top: 40px;
    padding-bottom: 40px;
  }
  .clock-col {
    & + & {
      margin-top: 20px;
    }
    &:before,
    &:after {
      display: none!important;
    }
  }
}
```

Java Script:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () =>
  requestAnimationFrame(updateTime)
)

function updateTime() {
  document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--timer-day', "'" + moment().format("dd") + "'");
  document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--timer-hours', "'" + moment().format("k") + "'");
  document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--timer-minutes', "'" + moment().format("mm") + "'");
  document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--timer-seconds', "'" + moment().format("ss") + "'");
  requestAnimationFrame(updateTime);
}
```

Comment: Wait wait. 1. What do you mean "combine" ? 2. Why do you "need" it ?

Comment: Your CSS in not CSS, but SCSS, needs preprocessor to compile CSS file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking to put everything in the same file, you put the CSS in a `style` element, and JS in a `script` element. Use this syntax:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>

      /* Your CSS goes here, in the style element */

    </style>
  </head>
  <body>

    <!-- Your HTML goes here, in the body element -->

    <script>

      // Your JS goes here, inside the script element, at the end of the body element

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to link the JS and CSS files to your html.
Try this:

```
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<filename>.css">
   <script src="<filename>.js"></script> 
</head>
```

Edit:
As pointed out in the comments, you will have to transpile your SCSS to CSS first

Comment: As @focusStyle pointed it out in a comment, it is not CSS but SCSS. It needs to be transpiled first.

Comment: And although that is the most common approach it is not the only one so "have to" is not entirely accurate

Answer (score 0):

I think you you are trying combine everything in a page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
 <style>
  .clock {
  &-day {
    &:before {
      content: var(--timer-day);
    }
  }
  &-hours {
    &:before {
      content: var(--timer-hours);
    }
  }
  &-minutes {
    &:before {
      content: var(--timer-minutes);
    }
  }
  &-seconds {
    &:before {
      content: var(--timer-seconds);
    }
  }
}

body {
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, #1870ed 0, #f18f88 100%);
  font-family: 'Montserrat', 'sans-serif';
  min-height: 100vh; 
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.clock {
  &-container {
    margin-top: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    background-color: #080808;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 60px 20px;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px rgba(255,255,255,.15), 0 15px 90px 30px rgba(0,0,0,.25);
    display: flex;
  }
  &-col {
    text-align: center;
    margin-right: 40px;
    margin-left: 40px;
    min-width: 90px;
    position: relative;
    &:not(:last-child):before,
    &:not(:last-child):after{
      content: "";
      background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.3);
      height: 5px;
      width: 5px;
      border-radius: 50%;
      display: block;
      position: absolute;
      right: -42px;
    }
    &:not(:last-child):before {
      top: 35%;
    }
    &:not(:last-child):after {
      top: 50%;
    }
  }
  &-timer {
    &:before {
      color: #fff;
      font-size: 4.2rem;
      text-transform: uppercase;
    }
  }
  &-label {
    color: rgba(255,255,255,.35);
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: .7rem;
    margin-top: 10px;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 825px) {
  .clock-container {
  flex-direction: column;
    padding-top: 40px;
    padding-bottom: 40px;
  }
  .clock-col {
    & + & {
      margin-top: 20px;
    }
    &:before,
    &:after {
      display: none!important;
    }
  }
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="clock-container">
  <div class="clock-col">
    <p class="clock-hours clock-timer">
    </p>
    <p class="clock-label">
      Hours
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="clock-col">
    <p class="clock-minutes clock-timer">
    </p>
    <p class="clock-label">
      Minutes
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="clock-col">
    <p class="clock-seconds clock-timer">
    </p>
    <p class="clock-label">
      Seconds
    </p>
  </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () =>
  requestAnimationFrame(updateTime)
)

function updateTime() {
  document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--timer-day', "'" + moment().format("dd") + "'");
  document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--timer-hours', "'" + moment().format("k") + "'");
  document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--timer-minutes', "'" + moment().format("mm") + "'");
  document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--timer-seconds', "'" + moment().format("ss") + "'");
  requestAnimationFrame(updateTime);
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```